# How to make a div go to next row with flex display container

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I make the last div go to the next line? The inline-row div has flex display.

```
<div class="row inline-row">
  <div class="input-cost">
    <label>Cost</label>
    <div class="input-description"></div>
    <input class="input-number" formControlName="cost">
  </div>

  <div class="input-discount">
    <label>Discount (%)</label>
    <div class="input-description"></div>
    <input class="input-number" formControlName="cost">        
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="form-helper">This div to new line</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.inline-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: can you add width to the container??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways you can achieve this.

1) You can set `width` to the `container` and add `flex-wrap:wrap;` so that the last element will automatically wrapped to the next line.

```css
.inline-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width:400px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="row inline-row">
  <div class="input-cost">
    <label>Cost</label>
    <div class="input-description"></div>
    <input class="input-number" formControlName="cost">
  </div>

  <div class="input-discount">
    <label>Discount (%)</label>
    <div class="input-description"></div>
    <input class="input-number" formControlName="cost">        
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="form-helper">This div to new line</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

2) In case you don't want to set width to the container then you can manually set the last div's `width` to `100%` so it will wrap to the next line

```css
.inline-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.inline-row div:nth-child(3){width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class="row inline-row">
  <div class="input-cost">
    <label>Cost</label>
    <div class="input-description"></div>
    <input class="input-number" formControlName="cost">
  </div>

  <div class="input-discount">
    <label>Discount (%)</label>
    <div class="input-description"></div>
    <input class="input-number" formControlName="cost">        
  </div>

  <div>
    <div class="form-helper">This div to new line</div>
  </div>
</div>
```